# Render loop can't access Assimp const scene variable

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d

In my main render loop I need to access Assimp's Scene node every frame to get the bone names from it but I get a crash every time. **I'm trying to print the root name as a test.** The debugger says that the scene variable isnt initialized, although I can access it locally just fine if I stay within Object.cpp. If I try to call it from the outside I get a crash. The myFSQ Object is a shared_ptr.

```
//Object.h
const aiScene *m_scene;

//Object.cpp
//myFSQ
Assimp::Importer importer;
m_scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs | aiProcess_GenSmoothNormals | aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices | aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace);
cout << "root node name 1 = " << m_scene->mRootNode->mName.data << endl;


//render loop
if (myFSQ->m_scene)
{
    cout << "access root node name 2 = " << access->mRootNode->mName.data << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for `Importer::ReadFile` reads "*The importer object keeps ownership of the data and will destroy it upon destruction*". Once the method where you call `ReadFile` returns, `importer` is destroyed so you can't access the data later.

You should declare `importer` at a larger scope, preferably as a member of your object class.

Comment: Increasing the scope of the importer is just bad design. The documentation specifies the existence of GetOrphanedScene(), which releases ownership, which would be a much better fix.

Comment: It says that GetOrphanedScene() is the absolute last resort...Do I want to take such drastic steps here?